# iOS App Submission with Storage to Amazon S3

Tags: ios, app-store, appstore-approval

I am almost ready to submit my app to Apple but I have a question re: private data storage.

The app is similar to 100's that are out there where you can rate a restaurant, add photo etc.  At some point there will be a 'web' component to this where you can view all of them but for now it is not ready.  However I would like to 'save' the info so when the web is ready, there will be data to populate.

I am only saving the photos and the data points that users are entering PLUS a unique id for each device that I can later match up to the users device.  Do I need an OPT OUT in my app for this?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think so.

But if the user from the app get information about storing the UDID of the device on your space could be a risky move. It's not that bad, but there are enough paranoid people in the Internet ;)

Comment: Ok.  I think I might add it in if I have time just to be safe.